# Robot Framework: Get a specific part of the url

Tags: python, regex, robotframework

I'm very new working with Python and Robot Framework, I have the following url:

https://site-of-the-company/r/x/a0l3h000001HlRxAAK/view

I'd like to get the id of the page: a0l3h000001HlRxAAK

Already tried using regex like this:

```
${url}=  Get Location
${id}=  Get Regexp Matches  ${url}  \\d
```

But got this:

```
${id} = ['0', '3', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1']
```

Comment: Hello! There are a number of other answers on Stack Overflow for using a regex for parsing parts of a URL. Which of those have you looked at, and what were they missing?    What's confusing about the documentation for Get Regexp Matches? If you're unfamiliar with regular expressions, consider looking at a tutorial, like https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html .

Comment: Is it correct to say you want everything between `/x/` and `/view`, or can the text before the id be something other than `/x/`?

Comment: Yes, everything between /x/ and /view. I just want to retrieve the id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest a generic solution using split from string library that is available in builtin ( robotframework ):

```
@{tokenized_uri}=   Split String  ${uri}   /
${domain} =     Get From List   ${tokenized_uri}    2
${_param} =     Get From List   ${tokenized_uri}    5
```

As you can see, the split happens with "/" char, then you get the element in the list you are interested in. There are other solutions, I found this one quite generic.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure the structure of the page will remain the same, you can use [`urllib.parse.urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#url-parsing) to get the path, split the path using `str.split` and access the id from the resulting array